# Increasing the counter in a list every two elements

Tags: python

I have a list of elements:

```
list = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
```

which I use in pairs in this way:

```
for x in range(0, len(list)-1):
    print(list[x], list[x+1])
```

This works and returns:

```
('elem1', 'elem2')
('elem2', 'elem3')
('elem3', 'elem4')
('elem4', 'elem5')
```

I would like to increase a counter every time I print a row. How can I do this?

Comment: what does the counter do as opposed to what it doesn't currently?

Comment: `x` is your counter as it is increasing every time. Or did I missed anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't use list as a variable name, that can cause some serious problems.

Second, the simple way is just initial a counter and increment it inside the loop.

```
li = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']

cnt = 0
for index in range(0, len(li)-1):
    cnt += 1
    print(li[index], li[index+1])

print cnt
```

Another elegant way to create the required output is:

```
li = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']

for cnt, (v, w) in enumerate(zip(li[:-1], li[1:])):
    print [v, w]

print cnt
```

Here we separate it into two lists, the first one is `['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4']`, the second is `['elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']`.

Each iteration we take one from the first list and the second from the second list.

Comment: `index - 1` in that case as we run through `len(li) -1`

Comment: `index + 1` if you want the count to start at 1, else, just `index`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution declares a variable called `count` and increases it every iteration

```
listX = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
count = 0
for x in range(0, len(listX)-1):
    print(list[x], list[x+1])
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable with the initial value you want before the for loop and increase it inside the for:

```
    counter = 0
    for x in range(0, len(list)-1):
        print(list[x], list[x+1])
        counter += 1
```